# How to add UITabBar in iphone using objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar

How to add add UITabBar programmatically for iphone app. Need some suggestion and sample code.

Comment: I did, but I don't get the solution to get started.

Comment: Max, please. I bought Objective C books, and have been digging into it for awhile, and I still have trouble with these things. He's asking how to create a UITabBar, NOT a UITabBarController... amazingly Apple documentation doesn't tell you how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
- (void) setUpTabBar {
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    firstViewController.title = @"First View";
    firstViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemSearch tag:0];
    UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    secondViewController.title = @"Second View";
    secondViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:1];
    UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc]init];
    thirdViewController.title = @"Third View";
    thirdViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemRecents tag:2];
    UINavigationController *thirdNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];

    ForthViewController *forthViewController = [[ForthViewController alloc]init];
    forthViewController.title = @"Forth View";
    forthViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemHistory tag:2];
    UINavigationController *forthNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:forthViewController];

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController, forthNavController, nil];
    tabBarController.delegate = self;             
    [self sizeViewToAvailableWindow:[tabBarController view]];

    [firstNavController release];
    [firstViewController release];

    [secondNavController release];
    [secondViewController release];

    [thirdNavController release];
    [thirdViewController release];

    [forthNavController release];
    [forthViewController release];
}
```

Here is the code for making TabBarController programmatically.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 30):

Here the two aspects....

First Aspect (**UITabBarController**):
        Here You can add multiple classes (i.e Viewcontrollers) to the UITabBarController as show in the previous answers...

Second Aspect (**UITabbar**):
        Here You can add the Tabbar in any view controller...And for this Tabbar you can add multiple UITabBar Items..and You can get the individual Tabbar Item Action.....

See the Below Code For **UITabBar**

---------> **Adding UITabBar**

```
UITabBar *myTabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
myTabBar.delegate=self;   //here you need import the protocol <UITabBarDelegate>
[self.view addSubview:myTabBar];
```

---------> **Adding Items to UITabBar**

```
NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Item1image.png"] tag:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:1 ];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemHistory tag:2 ];

[tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem1];
[tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem2];
[tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem3];

myTabBar.items = tabBarItems;
myTabBar.selectedItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0];
```

---------> **Getting The Item Actions in a Delegate Method**

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    NSInteger selectedTag = tabBar.selectedItem.tag;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)selectedTag);
    if (selectedTag == 0) {
        //Do what ever you want here
    } else if(selectedTag == 1) {
        //Do what ever you want
    } else { //if(selectedTag == 2)
        //Do what ever you want here
    }
}
```

---

**Update: (Swift 2.0)**
**1.** First Aspect (**UITabBarController**):
This will allow us to configure `UIViewController`s as `tabbar` items in `UITabBarController`.
Below is the basic approach for **UITabBarController**:

**---------> Adding UITabBarController** to window in appdelegate

```
let tabBarController = UITabBarController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
tabBarController.delegate = self // Need to import 'UITabBarControllerDelegate'
self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarController;
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
```

**---------> Configuring UIViewControllers**

```
let firstViewController = UIViewController()
firstViewController.title = "FirstVC"
firstViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Bookmarks, tag: 0)
let firstNavController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)

let secondViewController = UIViewController()
secondViewController.title = "SecondVC"
secondViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Contacts, tag: 1)
let secondNavController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController)

let thirdViewController = UIViewController()
thirdViewController.title = "ThirdVC"
thirdViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Downloads, tag: 2)
let thirdNavController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: thirdViewController)

let forthViewController = UIViewController()
forthViewController.title = "ForthVC"
forthViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Favorites, tag: 3)
let forthNavController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: forthViewController)
```

**---------> Attaching UIViewControllers to UITabBarController**

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [firstNavController, secondNavController, thirdNavController, forthNavController]
```

**---------> Receiving event in 'UITabBarControllerDelegate'**

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    print("didSelectViewController: \(viewController.title) ?")
}
```

**2.** Second Aspect (**UITabBar**):
This will allow us to create `tabbar` items. We can get event for individual item in delegate method 
Below is the basic approach for **UITabBar**:

**---------> Adding UITabBar** to a view

```
let frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - 49, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 49)
let tabBar: UITabBar = UITabBar(frame: frame)
tabBar.delegate = self // Need to import 'UITabBarDelegate'
self.view.addSubview(tabBar)
```

**---------> Preparing TabbarItems**

```
let tabBarItem1 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Bookmarks, tag: 0)
let tabBarItem2 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Contacts, tag: 1)
let tabBarItem3 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Downloads, tag: 2)
let tabBarItem4 = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: UITabBarSystemItem.Favorites, tag: 3)
```

**---------> Adding UITabBarItems to UITabBar**

```
tabBar.items = [tabBarItem1, tabBarItem2, tabBarItem3, tabBarItem4]
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBarItem1
```

**---------> Receiving event in 'UITabBarDelegate'**

```
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    let selectedTag:Int = (tabBar.selectedItem?.tag)!
    print(selectedTag)
    switch selectedTag {
    case 0:
        print("tabBarItem1")
        //Do what ever you want here
    case 1:
        print("tabBarItem2")
        //Do what ever you want here
    case 2:
        print("tabBarItem3")
        //Do what ever you want here
    default:
        print("tabBarItem4")
        //Do what ever you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer my friend @Ashok Kumar S

Comment: @YuvarajM. Make sure you set delegate.

Comment: @Thanks Ashok, morning itself i fix it.

Answer (score 1):

here is what u can do

```
    SubClassViewController1* vc1 = [[SubClassViewController1 alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
    nav1.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [vc1 release]; vc1 = nil;

    SubClassViewController2* vc2 = [[SubClassViewController2 alloc] init];
    vc2.title = @"List";
    UINavigationController* nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2];
    nav2.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [vc2 release]; vc2 = nil;

    SubClassViewController3* vc3 = [[SubClassViewController3 alloc] init];
    vc3.title = @"Scan";
    UINavigationController* nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc3];
    nav3.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [vc3 release]; vc3 = nil;

    SubClassViewController4* vc4 = [[SubClassViewController4 alloc] init];
    vc4.title = @"Setting";
    UINavigationController* nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc4];
    nav4.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [vc4 release]; vc4 = nil;

    UITabBarController* tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nil]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
    [nav1 release]; nav1 = nil;
    [nav2 release]; nav2 = nil;
    [nav3 release]; nav3 = nil;
    [nav4 release]; nav4 = nil;
    [tabBar release]; tabBar = nil;
```

This will create a tab bar with four tabs and each tab with its own viewcontroller and navigation controller, i.e each tab maintains its own stack to push and pop the view controller.
I hope that helps U.

Comment: How does one create a simple UITabBar without the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

To add some items to it, you can write:

```
NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"] tag:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"] tag:1];
[tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem];
[tabBarItems addObject:tabBarItem1];
tabBar.items = tabBarItems;
tabBar.selectedItem = [tabBarItems objectAtIndex:0];
```